# Setup rabbitmq cluster with puppet

Tags: rabbitmq, cluster-computing, puppet

I am trying to setup a rabbitmq cluster with puppet. I have nodeA that initiates the cluster and all other nodes should join nodeA's cluster using nodeA's hostname.
All other nodes execute the following code.

```
class { 'rabbitmq':
   service_manage => false,
   port => '5672',
   delete_guest_user => true,
   erlang_cookie => $erlang_hash,
   config_cluster    => true,
   cluster_nodes     => ['nodeA'],
   cluster_node_type => 'ram',
   wipe_db_on_cookie_change => true,
}
```

Nodes executing this puppet code can ping nodeA and puppet generates the following config file,

```
% This file managed by Puppet
% Template Path: rabbitmq/templates/rabbitmq.config
[
  {rabbit, [
    {cluster_nodes, {['rabbit@nodeA'], ram}},
    {cluster_partition_handling, ignore},
    {default_user, <<"guest">>},
    {default_pass, <<"guest">>}
  ]}
].
% EOF
```

nodeA is a disc node and the node trying to join nodeA's cluster is a ram node.

Unfortunately a node executing my puppet code doesn't join nodeA's cluster.

Comment: What errors are reported? What behavior do you expect instead? Please bear in mind that questions for existing documentation are not allowed.

Comment: I don't get any errors. None of the other nodes join nodeA's cluster.

Comment: Then whatever additional action is required must be coded into your Puppet manifest. Needs more information. How would you manually join a node?

Comment: I stop rabbitmq-server, copy erlang.cookie from nodeA, run rabbitmq-server -detached(only step I don't implement in puppet, not sure how to), restart rabbitmq-server, stop rabbitmq mnesia, run command to join nodeA's cluster and restart mnesia.

Comment: Ah. I see how this is difficult to model. Does the [official module](https://forge.puppetlabs.com/puppetlabs/rabbitmq) help at all?

Comment: This link has a section "Clustering", I think I have covered everything it says about clusters. https://github.com/puppetlabs/puppetlabs-rabbitmq/

Comment: So, did you get it sorted? Can you share what was wrong?

Comment: Rabbitmq-cluster requires all servers to be on the same network. My network wasn't setup right, hosts connected with each other over different vlans.

Comment: Did you ever get rabbit clustering working? I am having a hell of a time!